# Question about segmentation fault on std::stack push

Tags: c++, c++11, segmentation-fault, stack

I am working on a octree traversal algorithm. The current implementation uses a `std::queue` for such purpose, working flawlessly. However, I would like to use for such traversal a `std::stack`, as a depth first search will give better performance, avoiding testing non needed nodes.

However, when changing from one structure to another, I start getting segmentation faults on the `push()` function. Here is the stack report from `gdb`:

```
0x00005555555ae28d in __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<voxelizer::Node*>::construct<voxelizer::Node*, voxelizer::Node* const&> (this=0x7fffffffd7f0, __p=0x5555559abde8, __args#0=<error reading variable>)
    at /usr/include/c++/7/ext/new_allocator.h:136
136     { ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
(gdb) up
#1  0x00005555555acd1c in std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<voxelizer::Node*> >::construct<voxelizer::Node*, voxelizer::Node* const&> (__a=..., __p=0x5555559abde8, __args#0=<error reading variable>)
    at /usr/include/c++/7/bits/alloc_traits.h:475
475     { __a.construct(__p, std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
(gdb) up
#2  0x00005555555ab63e in std::deque<voxelizer::Node*, std::allocator<voxelizer::Node*> >::push_back (this=0x7fffffffd7f0, __x=<error reading variable>) at /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_deque.h:1547
1547            _Alloc_traits::construct(this->_M_impl,
(gdb) up
#3  0x00005555555aa29f in std::stack<voxelizer::Node*, std::deque<voxelizer::Node*, std::allocator<voxelizer::Node*> > >::push (this=0x7fffffffd7f0, __x=<error reading variable>)
    at /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_stack.h:226
226       { c.push_back(__x); }
```

I could not get my head around why, so I created a minimal, verifiable example where I could get rid of possible errors caused by any other part of the system. I reproduced the cotree Node structure, and created a small tree to traverse:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

// ==============================================================

class TestClass
{
  public:
    // Default constructor
    TestClass()
      : d(0)
      , children(nullptr)
    {
    }

    // Depth based constructor
    TestClass(int d_)
     : d(d_)
     , children(nullptr)
    {
      if(d > 0)
      {
        children = new TestClass*[8];
        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
          children[i] = new TestClass(d - 1);
        }
      }
    }

    // Copy  constructor
    TestClass(const TestClass & other_)
     : d(0)
     , children(nullptr)
    {
      _copy(other_);
    }

    // Move constructor
    TestClass(TestClass && other_)
      : d(0)
      , children(nullptr)
    {
      _move(std::move(other_));
    }

    // Destructor
    ~TestClass()
    {
      _clearChildren();
    }

    // Copy assignment operator
    TestClass & operator= (const TestClass & other_)
    {
      _copy(other_);
      return *this;
    }

    // Move assignment operator
    TestClass & operator= (TestClass && other_)
    {
      _move(std::move(other_));
      return *this;
    }

    int depth()
    {
      return d;
    }

    TestClass ** getChildren()
    {
      return children;
    }

  private:
    void _clearChildren()
    {
      if(children != nullptr)
      {
        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
          delete children[i];
        }

        delete[] children;
        children = nullptr;
      }
    }

    void _copy(const TestClass & other_)
    {
      d = other_.d;

      _clearChildren();
      if(other_.children != nullptr)
      {
        children = new TestClass*[8];
        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
          children[i] = new TestClass(*(other_.children[i]));
        }
      }
    }

    void _move(TestClass && other_)
    {
      d = other_.d;

      _clearChildren();
      children = std::move(other_.children);
    }

  private:
    int d;
    TestClass ** children;
};

// ==============================================================

typedef TestClass * TestClassPtr;

// ==============================================================

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{

  TestClassPtr test = new TestClass(5);

  stack<TestClassPtr> s;
  s.push(test);

  while(!s.empty())
  {
    TestClassPtr & next = s.top();
    s.pop();

    cout << "On depth " << next->depth() << endl;

    if(next->getChildren() != nullptr)
    {
      std::cout << "Adding children" << std::endl;
      for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
      {
        if(next->getChildren()[i]->getChildren() != nullptr)
        {
          s.push(next->getChildren()[i]);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  cout << "Done" << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

By running it I was able to reproduce the problem, in the `push()` method as well:

```
On depth 5
Adding children
On depth 3
Adding children
On depth 1
Adding children
Segmentation fault
```

So I went on to revising the documentation. Note that I'm using C++11. The requirements for a default `std::stack` can be inherited from the requirements of using a `std::deque`, as it is the default container used. Since C++11, the main requirement is to be a **complete type** and **Erasable** I made sure the destructor was accessible. Also, for the sake of safe proofing, I implemented a default constructor, copy constructor, move constructor, copy assignment, and move assignment.

So I believe my class is **Erasable**, but perhaps not complete. By modifying the traverse loop in the example and adding the "SAFE PROOF LINE" if:

```
if(next->getChildren() != nullptr)
{
  std::cout << "Adding children" << std::endl;
  for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
  {
    // SAFE PROOF LINE
    if(next->getChildren()[i]->getChildren() != nullptr)
    {
      s.push(next->getChildren()[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

I was able to get rid of the segmentation fault. The nodes which this line discard are the leaf nodes, which does not have children and, thus, their `children` variable is a `nullptr`.

My questions:

- Does this means a `nullptr` pointer makes a type incomplete?
- The point of using this raw memory double pointer is to safe as much
  memory as possible, is there anyway I can make it work without having
  to substitute it for a stack array or a `std::vector`?

Thanks.

Comment: How would an std::vector "waste" memory in your opinion?

Comment: @MateuszGrzejek I never said it is a waste, I said to save as much memory as possible. The double pointer is 8 bytes in size, the vector is 24 bytes

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I did. What I did is in accordance to what that post says, you use `delete[]` for memory allocated with `new []`. Check the code and see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems to go wrong right from the start

```
while(!s.empty())
{
    TestClassPtr & next = s.top();
    s.pop();
```

`next` is a reference to the object on the top of the stack, but the very next line removes that object, so the reference becomes invalid.

Simple answer is to not use a reference and just copy the top of the stack.

```
while(!s.empty())
{
    TestClassPtr next = s.top();
    s.pop();
```

Comment: You are right, that fixes the problem. But why this does not happen with a `queue`? I mean, to retrieve a reference which afterwards I `pop()`

Comment: @GreyFox If you have a reference to something deleted, this causes undefined behaviour. UB can lead to anything, including the thing you intended to do. This might be the case for your queue.

Answer (score 0):

gdb says that the `push` argument is invalid:

```
push (this=0x7fffffffd7f0, __x=<error reading variable>)
```